# Kernel test fails with 'Error: Call to undefined function drupal_valid_test_ua()'

Tags: testing

My kernel tests are failing with:

```
Error: Call to undefined function drupal_valid_test_ua()

/Users/joachim/Sites/drupal-core-composer/repos/drupal/core/tests/Drupal/KernelTests/KernelTestBase.php:273
```

I'm running from the repo root with:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit web/core/tests/Drupal/KernelTests/Core/Entity/EntityApiTest.php
```

and phpunit.xml is configured with:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="web/core/tests/bootstrap.php" colors="true"
```

This is a configuration that normally works on D8, but here I'm on D9, and I'm symlinking the core repo in as a Composer file repo.